# ajax validation in TblActiveForm

Tags: ajax, yii, yii1.x, yii-validation

I faced with some problem in TblActiveForm. I have few models in 1 action and I need validate it in ajax. The simple server validation works fine, but I can't do ajax validation. In view file I have 3 tabs each of them display corresponding models.I don't have any error message.
Here is my action:

```
  public function actionUpdateModule($id)
{
    $model = ModulesInfo::model()->with('rightsInfo')->findbypk($id);
    $RI_model = RightsInfo::model()->findAll('module_id=' . $id);
    $status = true;
    $model_numeration = new ModuleNumeration;
    if (isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] === 'add_module') {

        echo TbActiveForm::validate($model_numeration);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
    $model_numeration->unsetAttributes();

    if (Yii::app()->request->getQuery('ModuleNumeration')) {
        $model_numeration->scenario = 'search';
        $model_numeration->attributes = Yii::app()->request->getQuery('ModuleNumeration');
        $status = false;
    }
    $controllers = $model_numeration->getControllerFromModule($model->url_name);
    $moduleNumeration  =  Yii::app()->request->getPost('ModuleNumeration');
    if (isset($_POST['ModulesInfo']) && $moduleNumeration ) {
        $model->name = $_POST['ModulesInfo']['name'];
        $model->icon = $_POST['ModulesInfo']['icon'];
        $model->url_name = $_POST['ModulesInfo']['url_name'];

        $model->save();
        //check if select controller, if yes validate model
        if (Yii::app()->request->getPost('ModuleNumeration') &&
            Yii::app()->request->getPost('ModuleNumeration')['controller_id'] != false
        ) {
            $model_numeration->attributes = Yii::app()->request->getPost('ModuleNumeration');
            $model_numeration->module_id = $model->id;
            $model_numeration->scenario = 'update';
            if ($model_numeration->validate() && $model_numeration->save()) {
                $status = true;
            } else {
                $status = false;
            }
        }

        if (isset($_POST['RightsInfo']) && is_array($_POST['NewRightsInfo'])) {
            foreach ($_POST['RightsInfo'] as $exist_r_id => $exist_r) {
                if ($exist_r['code'] == '') {
                    RightsInfo::model()->deleteByPk($exist_r_id);
                } else {
                    $exist_r_model = RightsInfo::model()->findbypk($exist_r_id);
                    $exist_r_model->code = $exist_r['code'];
                    $exist_r_model->name = $exist_r['name'];
                    $exist_r_model->save();
                }
            }
        }
        if (isset($_POST['NewRightsInfo']) && is_array($_POST['NewRightsInfo']) && !empty($_POST['NewRightsInfo'])) {
            foreach ($_POST['NewRightsInfo'] as $right) {
                if ($right['code'] != "") {
                    $RI_model = new RightsInfo;
                    $RI_model->name = $right['name'];
                    $RI_model->code = $right['code'];
                    $RI_model->module_id = $id;
                    $RI_model->save();
                }
            }
        }

            ModuleNumeration::setFlashMessage($status);


    }

    $this->render('addmodule', array(
        'model' => $model,
        'RI_model' => $RI_model,
        'controllers' => $controllers,
        'model_numeration' => $model_numeration
    ));

}
```

View file:

```
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget(
                'bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm',
                array(
                    'layout' => TbHtml::FORM_LAYOUT_HORIZONTAL,
                    'id' => 'add_module',
                    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
                    'enableClientValidation'=>false,
                    'clientOptions' => array(
                        'validateOnSubmit' => true,
                        'validateOnChange' => false,
                    ),
            )); ?>

            <fieldset>

                <legend><?php echo Yii::t('modules', 'General information'); ?></legend>

                <?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model, 'name', array('span' => 6)); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model, 'icon', array('span' => 6)); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model, 'url_name', array('span' => 6)); ?>

                <legend></legend>

                <label class="control-label" for="RightsInfos">Rights</label>

                <div id="RightsInfos">

                    <?php
                    if (!empty($model->rightsInfo))
                        foreach ($model->rightsInfo as $right) {
                            echo "<div class='controls'>";
                            echo 'code: &nbsp;' . TbHtml::textField('RightsInfo[' . $right->id . '][code]', $right->code, array('span' => 1));
                            echo '&nbsp; name: &nbsp;' . TbHtml::textField('RightsInfo[' . $right->id . '][name]', $right->name, array('span' => 4));
                            echo '</div><br>';
                        }
                    ?>

                    <div class="controls">
                    <?php echo 'code: &nbsp;' . TbHtml::textField('NewRightsInfo[0][code]', '', array('span' => 1)); ?>
                    <?php echo 'name: &nbsp;' . TbHtml::textField('NewRightsInfo[0][name]', '', array('span' => 4)); ?>
                    <?php echo TbHtml::link('+', $url = '#', array('onclick' => 'javascript:$.registActions();')); ?>
                </div>
                <br>

        </div>
        </fieldset>
        <?php
        if (!isset($model->id))
            echo TbHtml::formActions(array(
               TbHtml::ajaxButton(Yii::t('common', 'Update'),Yii::app()->controller->createUrl('/Admin/Adminpanel/updateModule',
            ));
        else
            echo TbHtml::formActions(array(
                 TbHtml::ajaxButton(Yii::t('common', 'Update'),Yii::app()->controller->createUrl('/Admin/Adminpanel/updateModule',
            ));
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="code">
        <fieldset>
            <legend><?php echo Yii::t('modules', 'Code that reference to action') ?></legend>
        </fieldset>

        <div class="controls">
            <?php echo $form->label($model_numeration, 'controller_id', array('class' => 'control-label')); ?>
            <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model_numeration, 'controller_id', $controllers, array('empty' => '', 'rows' => '7')); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model_numeration, 'controller_id', array('class' => 'alert-error'),false); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <?php echo $form->label($model_numeration, 'action_id', array('class' => 'control-label')); ?>
            <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model_numeration, 'action_id', array(), array('empty' => '-', 'class' => 'ееее')); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model_numeration, 'action_id', array('class' => 'alert-error'),false); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <?php echo $form->label($model_numeration, 'code', array('class' => 'control-label')); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($model_numeration, 'code'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model_numeration, 'code', array('class' => 'alert-error'),false); ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        if (!isset ($model->id)) {
            echo TbHtml::formActions(array(
                TbHtml::ajaxButton(Yii::t('common', 'Update'),Yii::app()->controller->createUrl('/Admin/Adminpanel/updateModule',array('id' => $model->id)),array(), array('color' => '#333333')),
            ));
        } else {
            echo TbHtml::formActions(array(
                TbHtml::ajaxButton(Yii::t('common', 'Update'),Yii::app()->controller->createUrl('/Admin/Adminpanel/updateModule',array('id' => $model->id)),array(), array('color' => '#333333')),
            ));
        }
        ?>
    </div>

    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Comment: What is the actual error you get?

Comment: I don't  have any  error

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem with your error messages is that in the third parameter of the method error you are setting the enableAjaxValidation to false

```
 <?php echo $form->error($model_numeration,
                        'controller_id',
                         array('class' => 'alert-error'),
                         false);//here is the problem ?>
```

Try setting it to true

```
<?php echo $form->error($model_numeration,
                        'controller_id',
                         array('class' => 'alert-error'),
                         true);?>
```

Comment: Thank for replay. I tried it also, but it still not working.

Comment: I've been running some tests, at it seems that another problem could be the use of ajax button, can't you use submit button instead?

Comment: Yes ,I used instead ajax button. I fixed it via  placed  ajax validate  after this part of code  $model_numeration->scenario = 'update'; But now I don't see error message. I set after validate method which run only when model has validate error - form don't submit if there are not any validation error.